# InvalidGroupIdException: in Kafka scala consumer program even after setting group.id

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing the

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: To use the
>   group management or offset commit APIs, you must provide a valid
>   group.id in the consumer configuration.

error when running the below kafka consumer API from command line written in scala. what could be be the issue?

```
    object KafkaAggregateConsumerApp extends App{
  try {
    val properties: Properties = new Properties()
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "0:9092") 
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer")
    properties.put("group.id", "console-consumer-myapp")

    val consumerApp = new KafkaConsumer[String, Int](properties)
    consumerApp.subscribe(Pattern.compile("kafkaaggregationsource1"))

    try {
      while (true) {
        val consumerRecord: ConsumerRecords[String, Int] = consumerApp.poll(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
        consumerRecord.forEach((each) => println(each.key() + " " + each.value()))
      }
    } finally {
      consumerApp.close()
    }
  }
  catch{
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [source code](https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/78d55741fcb222964d0ab5e4eaa01450e331764b/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L2295) I can see that this `InvalidGroupIdException` is thrown when `groupId` is `null`,

> ```
> private void maybeThrowInvalidGroupIdException() {
>     if (groupId == null)
>         throw new InvalidGroupIdException("To use the group management or offset commit APIs, you must " +
>                 "provide a valid " + ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG + " in the consumer configuration.");
> }
> ```

I would suggest to set the group id using `ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG` instead of `"group.id"`:

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "console-consumer-myapp")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried that way as well but same error!

Comment: Also, is the group id something I set in the consumer for the first time? or do I have to use an already available one? because when I check the list of available groups using kafka-consumer-groups.sh I found some consumer groups created for my topic without me specifying to create explicitly before running this code, i.e there is already a consumer group created like "console-consumer-12423", even using that doesn't work.

Comment: It's likely because of compatibility issues with Confluent 5.1.2 and Scala 2.12. I now downgraded scala and checking.